# Confused with Right Hand Rule. Finding the direction of Force on wire segment due to magnetic field?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, vectors

[image]

First of all, this is not a HW question, and I know the answer.

I know I can find the direction of F which is `F = IL x B`

So I tried to put my index finger (I) pointing to right, and middle finger (B) pointing downward. This makes my thumb to point `Into the Page`. But the answer is actually the `D direction`. How does this work?

Also, the magnitude of the force is 61.9 N, but I am also confused of getting this answer using `F = IL x B`. Please help!

Comment: One thing is, since the current points into the page, you point your index finger at the screen, not to the right, then your middle finger points down and your thumb points correctly to the left in the direction of D. If you just directly use the Lorentz force law you get $$F = IL \times B = (4.3\text{ A}\cdot 3.23 \text{ m} (-\hat{z})) \times 6.3\text{ T}(-\hat{y}) = (4.3\cdot 3.23 \cdot 6.3 \text{A m T})(\hat{z}\times \hat{y}) = - 87.5007\text{ N} \hat{x}$$ It would appear that whatever answer you have in magnitude is a typo of some sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do the right hand rule.  Yours does not work.

Try this one and see if it makes sense for you:  form a right-angled triad with your thumb and first two fingers.   $\vec{c}=\vec{a}\times \vec{b}$.   First finger:  $\vec{a}$.  Second finger:  $\vec{b}$.   Thumb:  the resultant, $\vec{c}$

In your example, first finger into the page, second finger down, thumb points in the $D$ direction.

Comment: Thanks. It works! To clarify, can I ALWAYS use this when getting the direction of a cross-product? What are other right hand rules that I have to be aware of? I'm not sure how the `curling` finger works. Also how does F = IL x B become 61.9 N in the question?

Comment: I think 61.9 N is incorrect.   Yes, you can *always* use this method.  I, too, find the curl method confusing.   There's another method using the palm of the hand that many people like.  I'm not familiar enough to describe it.  Maybe someone else will.  I *always* use the method I described ... but it really is a matter of personal preference.