# Using the right-hand rule to find the direction of the created field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, vectors

First of all, this is not a HW question, and I know the answer.

[image]

I tried to use the right hand rule to solve this, but I am only familiar with the right hand rule that uses the index finger, middle finger, and the thumb.

The answer for this question is the `F-direction` and the explanation to the answer says

> "Use the right-hand rule to find the direction of the created field. Point your finger in the direction of the current and your fingers will curl in the same way the magnetic field curls around the wire."

But I am not even sure how that gives me the `F-direction`. The direction of the current is right, but how am I supposed to curl my fingers?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/395672/2451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the right hand rule on wire 1, they just want to know what is the direction of the B field at wire 1 due to wire 2. However, you do need to use the right hand rule on wire 2.

Usually when you use the right hand rule you will deal with a cross product. In the case of the magnetic force:

```
F_b = (q*v) X B
```

where F_b is magnetic force (vector) , q = charge, v = velocity of charge (vector), and B is magnetic field (vector).

In order to find the direction of the B field of wire 2 you have to first point your thumb toward the velocity of current in wire 2 which is into the plane, then as you curl your fingers, you will get that the direction of the B field is clockwise. This means that B field from wire 2 forms concentric circles that go clockwise.

Note: the magnetic field from the current going into the page (wire 2) should have concentric vectors going clockwise, so at wire 1, B field due to wire 2 should be pointing in the F-direction.

there is a youtube video where they show the B field of two wires with opposite current directions, which is similar to your question:

[magnetic fields of wires](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nfSJ62mzKyY)